# To move selective images from one folder to another

Tags: python, image, operating-system, classification, shutil

I have sorted out few set images(32x32) into another folder.
I wish to remove the same images but of the pixel value 64x64. I have written this code but somehow it doesn't find the images in the directory. If you could tell what am i doing wrong here:

```
filtered_images = r'C:\Users\320067835\Desktop\Thesis\Data\png\Quality Check_sorted_images'

classes = ['Abdomen','Chest-Ap','Chest-Lat','CSpine-ap','CSpine-lat',
           'elbow','Foot-AP','Foot-lat','Hand-AP','Hand-lat','Hand-obli',
           'Hip-ap','Knee-AP', 'Knee-Lat', 'LSpine-ap-pa', 'LSpine-lat',
           'Pelvis-AP' , 'Shoulder-AP', 'Shoulder-Axial', 'Skull-ap-pa',
           'Skull-lat', 'TSpine-ap', 'TSpine-lat']

source_folder = r'C:\Users\320067835\Desktop\Thesis\Data\png\data_processed_cropped_64'

def sorted_images():
    for a_class in classes:
        source_path = os.path.join(source_folder,a_class)
        a_class_num = classes.index(a_class)
        for img in os.listdir(source_path):
            if img in os.listdir(filtered_images):
               continue
            else:
                shutil.move(img,r'C:\Users\320067835\Desktop\Thesis\Data\png\Quality check_64_64')


sorted_images()
```

Error : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Abdomen_0.png'

Comment: I suspect that you are looking in the wrong directory for the source. `img` is a file_name not a full path.  What is your current directory when performing the `shutil.move` operation?  `import os` and `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: import os. Its the destination where i would like to move the images.

Comment: The images are sorted into the folder of 'Quality check_sorted_images' which am trying to compare with regard to the name (image names) with the folder 'data_processed_cropped_64'

Comment: Look at my previous comment again.  You are trying to move a file that does not exist in your current directory. The error you are getting is essentially `No such file or directory: '.\Abdomen_0.png`. If you print out your current working directory, I think you'll find that you are in the wrong dir.  it's going to be something like `shutil.move(os.path.join(filtered_images, img), r'C:\Users\32067835...')`

Comment: Yes, correct I checked my directory. I had to further mention the folder using os.path.join. Thank You!